# Why do XNA/Monogame models create new BasicEffect instances?

Tags: xna, 3d, monogame, models, graphic-effects

My question is fairly straightforward, I think. Using Monogame, when I load a model using `contentManager.Load<Model>("Model")`, the model's mesh has a `BasicEffect` attached. That means that if I load multiple models, I'll have multiple `BasicEffect` instances created, which seems wasteful. Based on other questions I've seen here (and based on instinct), I shouldn't need multiple effects for rendering simple models, but those effects are created by the content pipeline when the model is imported.

How do I resolve this problem? Is there a way to tell Monogame to not create effects on load, or do I have to override the effects created by the models manually? Is there something I'm missing in my logic?

Comment: I got around this in my XNA days by making a custom model class, its not much work. You could almost take the mono model class and remove all the effect stuff. That will get you 90% of the way and then you can setup your render pipeline to work how you like. That way you also decuple your mesh data from your shaders.

Comment: I wonder if your answer lies in one of Shawn Hargreaves blogs about XNA. All these posts cover XNA: http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html Look at the "Shader" category for interesting posts about using or not using the BasicEffect.